# IdentityServer4 doesn't redirect

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, oauth-2.0, identityserver4

I'm implementing IdentityServer4 as my authentication service for a mobile application with "Authorization Code Grant with PKCE". Login works successfully but it doesn't redirect, it stays stuck at /connect/authorize/callback and after some time error 502 Bad Gateway appears and the last message in the console log is "Creating Authorization Code Flow response."

Code:

```cs
new Client
{
    ClientId = "app",
    ClientName = App",
    AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Code,
    RequireClientSecret = false,
    RequirePkce = false,
    RequireConsent = false,
    RedirectUris = { "net.websites.example-site://oauth2redirect" },

    // this scopes can be used by this client
    AllowedScopes =
    {
        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,  
        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile,                           
        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Email,   
        "api",                                       

    AccessTokenLifetime = 7200,
    IdentityTokenLifetime = 7200,
}
```

Log:

```cs
[16:50:55 INF] Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:5000/connect/authorize/callback?nonce=ckf7_szTJaEwCT6TbQXCPuUmqt7L71hyrttk7t91fys&response_type=code&code_challenge_method=S256&scope=openid%20profile%20email%20api&code_challenge=G7W07PUgQozuiLN92tJFY5bKrMryBlXoR00qY1lHac4&redirect_uri=net.websites.example-site%3A%2F%2Foauth2redirect&client_id=app&state=OfdtNuzqL60F0vvkys-s_k_kch9wGiifB8i-IzHxRw0
[16:50:55 INF] No cached response available for this request.
[16:50:55 INF] AuthenticationScheme: Identity.Application was successfully authenticated.
[16:50:55 INF] AuthenticationScheme: Identity.Application was successfully authenticated.
[16:50:55 INF] AuthenticationScheme: Identity.Application was successfully authenticated.
[16:50:55 DBG] Request path /connect/authorize/callback matched to endpoint type Authorize
[16:50:55 DBG] Endpoint enabled: Authorize, successfully created handler: IdentityServer4.Endpoints.AuthorizeCallbackEndpoint
[16:50:55 INF] Invoking IdentityServer endpoint: IdentityServer4.Endpoints.AuthorizeCallbackEndpoint for /connect/authorize/callback
[16:50:55 DBG] Start authorize callback request
[16:50:55 DBG] User in authorize request: 87882d3f-3802-4db4-be2a-e85bb97f05c1
[16:50:55 DBG] Start authorize request protocol validation
[16:50:55 DBG] Checking for PKCE parameters
[16:50:55 INF] ValidatedAuthorizeRequest
{
  "ClientId": "app",
  "ClientName": "App",
  "RedirectUri": "net.websites.example-site://oauth2redirect",
  "AllowedRedirectUris": [
    "net.websites.example-site://oauth2redirect"
  ],
  "SubjectId": "87882d3f-3802-4db4-be2a-e85bb97f05c1",
  "ResponseType": "code",
  "ResponseMode": "query",
  "GrantType": "authorization_code",
  "RequestedScopes": "openid profile email api",
  "State": "OfdtNuzqL60F0vvkys-s_k_kch9wGiifB8i-IzHxRw0",
  "Nonce": "ckf7_szTJaEwCT6TbQXCPuUmqt7L71hyrttk7t91fys",
  "SessionId": "bcd41f50110a7bd67eac99168d969ad4",
  "Raw": {
    "nonce": "ckf7_szTJaEwCT6TbQXCPuUmqt7L71hyrttk7t91fys",
    "response_type": "code",
    "code_challenge_method": "S256",
    "scope": "openid profile email api",
    "code_challenge": "G7W07PUgQozuiLN92tJFY5bKrMryBlXoR00qY1lHac4",
    "redirect_uri": "net.websites.example-site://oauth2redirect",
    "client_id": "app",
    "state": "OfdtNuzqL60F0vvkys-s_k_kch9wGiifB8i-IzHxRw0"
  }
}
[16:50:55 DBG] Client is configured to not require consent, no consent is required
[16:50:55 DBG] Creating Authorization Code Flow response.
```

Comment: Just after "Creating Authorization Code Flow", IdentityServer4 tries to save the code in the PersistedGrants table. Could it be that you have a connectivity problem with your persistence or that you have not configured your PersistedGrantStore correctly?

Comment: @Alpha75 thanks! you are right, my problem was the implementation of IPersistedGrantStore